# nginx lua body_filter_by_lua_block need to execute sleep API disabled in the context of content_by_lua*

Tags: nginx

I need to make body filter sleep before response

```
location /configure/result.php {

       body_filter_by_lua_block   {
           --I am using ngx.arg[1] content return here if content contains somevalue then sleep
           --Need to execute sleep code before response =>
           ngx.sleep(60) --API disabled in the context of content_by_lua??
       }
    }
}
```

But i cant execute sleep function in body filter API disabled in the context of content_by_lua* is there any other method i can use

I rebuild source code to be able to use sleep function in body filters but it did not work the error "no co ctx was found" some suggestions would really help me i found out that i can use the (echo_sleep 10.0;) from nginx but it does so before the content from server has been requested

Answer (score 0):

You can use access_by_lua to make request to "/" but then unfortunately you will have double the data request sent